# Push Notification not working if we force stop the app mannually

Tags: android, push-notification, xtify

I have moved my app notification code from C2DM to GCM. In this i have a inbox for notification. Everything is working as expected. But notification doesn't work in below scenario:

I have installed the app. If I send notification, it comes to notification bar and in inbox also. If i force close the application from settings. Now, If we try to send the notification again to the device then we are not getting notification in notification bar but it is coming in notification inbox.

Note: I am using android 2.3. 
For ICS and Jelly Bean: I have read in this [post](https://groups.google.com/group/android-gcm/tree/browse_frm/month/2012-08/7e74aab31da818e1?rnum=11&lnk=nl&pli=1)  that if you force stop the app from settings then u will not get notification. Is it same problem here?

thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome! Please share the piece of code that wont work for the community to help you

Answer (score 3):

Yes that's true. If you force stop the app, the message can't be received (unlike iOS/APNS). The Xtify service will be restarted and messages will be received when the user re-opens the app or the user restarts his/her device.

Comment: I don't agree with this. Because, if you Force Quit the Facebook application, the messages are still received for Facebook application. I think, there should be a mechanism by which the messages can be received.

Comment: did you find a way out ?

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838415/gcm-push-notification-works-after-app-force-stop