# Phonegap PushPlugin Android: push doesn't work when app is updated

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-pushplugin

I've successfully integrated the PushPlugin for receiving push notifications on iOS and Android (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin). My problem is that, after I update my app with a new build (without uninstalling and reinstalling), push notifications stop working. I have to manually start the app before they start working again. Is there a way to keep the GCMBroadcastReceiver running through the update?

Push notifications are correctly received and displayed in all of these scenarios:

- App is running in background
- App has been stopped from the task manager
- Phone restarted and app is not running
- Phone restarted and app is running in background

Push notifications are not received, as expected, in these scenarios:

- App is running in foreground (don't want to lose current place in app)
- App has been force-quit (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20838611/2782404)
- Phone restarted and app is running in foreground

Comment: I think you’ll need to `re-register` a device when done with update and make sure that GCM running well, please refer to [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-register) and [here](https://blog.pushbullet.com/2014/02/12/keeping-google-cloud-messaging-for-android-working-reliably-techincal-post/) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bjiang thanks for your response, your second link https://blog.pushbullet.com/2014/02/12/keeping-google-cloud-messaging-for-android-working-reliably-techincal-post/ is extremely helpful.

The answer to this question is that re-registration needs to happen after the app is updated, and after the Android OS version is updated, to keep push notifications working reliably.