# Will FCM woke up an non-whitelisted Android app's process after it is killed?

Tags: android

I know this problem has been asked many times and I have seen most of the posts saying the app process won't be launched after it is killed.

I just have tested this but I found this behavior is not very consistent. I am using the "messaging" example app from "ApiDemo" from google. This "messaging" app is really simple and it doesn't have any special things such as automatically launching after device reboot, etc, so very basic app.
What I have tested this are:
1. Swipe the app from the task manager,e.g. long press the home button and close all. 
I double checked the Application manager from System setting to make sure the process is killed. Then I send the "data" type FCM and its process WAS CREATED.

2. Rebooted the device and double check the Application manager and its process was not running. Then I send the "data" type FCM and its process WAS CREATED.
3. "Force Stop" from the Application manager and then I send the "data" type FCM and its process WAS NOT CREATED.

I am using the com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2 and tried both the priority "high" and "normal" whose behavior is the same.

So is there any official doc saying about this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCM push notification works after app Force Stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838415/gcm-push-notification-works-after-app-force-stop)

Comment: Thanks, that answers the 3. What about 1 and 2.