# Android: How can I handle GCM message when app is force killed

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android app that will receive GCM message from server and has to show notification to the user. How can I handle this situation when app is force killed?

I am thinking of creating a sticky service to handle this situation but I am not sure if this is the right approach?

Also, will the GCM message be handled when app is killed by the OS itself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCM push notification works after app Force Stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838415/gcm-push-notification-works-after-app-force-stop)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android app not receiving Firebase Notification when app is stopped from multi-task tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504805/android-app-not-receiving-firebase-notification-when-app-is-stopped-from-multi-t)