# Google Chrome keeps working after force stop on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, push, restart

After I force stopped Google Chrome on Android, it continues to show web push notifications. But starting from version 3.1 of Android it is impossible to get any broadcast\notifcation after force stop of application.

How can it be?

Comment: An app in the stopped state will not respond to any implicit broadcasts. An app in the stopped state will respond to explicit broadcasts, ones using an explicit `Intent`. Any such use of an explicit `Intent` moves the app out of the stopped state, after which it will behave normally. "it continues to show web push notifications" -- I do not know much about these. Perhaps they are using Firebase Cloud Messaging, which (as I understand it) would use an explicit broadcast.

Comment: You are right, if you force stop any application you are not able to receive any broadcasts or restart service for example. You also are not able to get push from firebase, even if it has a high priority. 

I tested it, also I took some information from this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838415/gcm-push-notification-works-after-app-force-stop

But Google Chrome behaves in some other way. I want to know reason why. Maybe Google Services, that has some admin access are able to restart Google Chrome

Comment: "You also are not able to get push from firebase evet if it has a high priority" -- that would surprise me, as it is definitely using explicit `Intents`. Also, bear in mind that Chrome is from Google, and Android is from Google, and Google can give Chrome extra benefits than ordinary Android apps can have. Plus, Chrome is pre-installed on many Android devices, and pre-installed apps can have extra benefits that ordinary Android apps cannot have.