# Android app wont receive any notifications when app is terminated (force stopped)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've started using firebase very recently and for the past 2 days I'm trying to get FCM to work, and it does work on iOS and Web as planned. But on Android I've gotten the issue that I always receive this error when trying to get notifications while app is killed (Force stopped). This doesnt happen on iOS for example there everything works fine. Thanks for any help.

```
broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000000 pkg= (has extras) }
```

this is my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
    <permission android:name="com.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <application
        android:label="Example"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                    android:value="example_notification" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

main.dart:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  debugPrint("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  await setupFlutterNotifications();
  showFlutterNotification(message);
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}

Future<void> _showNotification(String title, String body) async {
  // show user notification
  // Initialize the flutter_local_notifications plugin
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    // Configure Android notification settings
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
    InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);

    // Configure the notification details
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'example_notification',
      'example',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.max,
      ticker: 'ticker',
    );
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
    NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    // Display the notification
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      title ?? '',
      body ?? '',
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'notification',
    );
  } else {
    // Configure iOS notification settings
    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
    InitializationSettings(
      iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);

    // Display the notification
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      title ?? '',
      body ?? '',
      const NotificationDetails(),
      payload: 'notification',
    );
  }

}

late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;

bool isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = false;

Future<void> setupFlutterNotifications() async {
  if (isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized) {
    return;
  }

  channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'example_notification',
    'example', // title
    description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.high,
  );

  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  /// Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow
  /// heads up notifications.
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
  isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = true;
}

void showFlutterNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channelDescription: channel.description,
          // TODO add a proper drawable resource to android, for now using
          //      one that already exists in example app.
          icon: 'launch_background',
        ),
      ),
    );
  } else {
    //Handle iOS notification
    var apple = message.notification?.apple;
    if (apple != null && notification != null && !kIsWeb) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        const NotificationDetails(
          iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
            presentAlert: true,
            presentBadge: true,
            presentSound: true,
          )
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}

Future initLogging() async {
  Logger.root.activateLogcat();
  Logger.root.level = Level.ALL;
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (!kIsWeb) {
    await Permission.notification.isDenied.then((value) {
      if (value) {
        Permission.notification.request();
      }
    });
  }
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  // Set the background messaging handler early on, as a named top-level function
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  // Set logging to logcat for easier debugging and get current Platform

  await initLogging();
  Logger log = Logger('main');
  log.info('Starting app');
  log.info("FireBase token: ${await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken()}");

  if (!kIsWeb) {
    await setupFlutterNotifications();
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I've tried adding all sorts of permissions etc to my manifest but for some reason it doesnt work. It can only handle notifications when the app is in the backround or foreground but not in an termianted status (only Android). iOS and Web are working great.

This also happens when I download the app from the Google Play store.

Comment: post the relevant code for dart push notification code as well.

Comment: can you also share the notification payload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After conducting a more thorough investigation into the topic, it appears that this behavior is intentional. If a user force stops an app, the app can no longer listen for notifications, and notifications will not be delivered.

For more information on this topic, I recommend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838415/gcm-push-notification-works-after-app-force-stop).